# AVCam output through HDMI adapter locked to portrait only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, avcam

I'm by no means an iOS developer though I did sign up for a year, and only have very basic coding abilities.

I'm working with the AVCam project to output a clean 720p video feed via an HDMI adapter from iPhone 4S and iPad2 to ingest into Telestream Wirecast via Black Magic Intensity Pro.  So far I have managed to remove the toolbar and buttons and hide the focus mode text, so on the iPhone/iPad screen it is a beautiful clean auto-focus video feed from the rear camera.

My question is, once I plug that into the AV adapter I get a rotated portrait view on a hdtv? Weird! Other than that the image quality seems great and the blackmagic intensity pro finds it fine at 720p60.

Why is it outputting to portrait only?